# What is the semantically correct name for two objects that could share the same name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, naming-conventions, naming

I have this code below:

```
@interface CustomClass

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *items;

@end

@implementation CustomClass

- (NSUInteger)indexOfItem:(CustomItem *)item
{
    for (CustomItem *siblingItem in _items) {

        // ...
    }
}

@end
```

I'm curious about my naming schema. I'm comparing two objects that both deserve to be named "item". The first "item" is the one passed as a parameter and the second one is the "item" found in the stored "items" of the class. If it was UIViews I could name it "siblingView" or "subview" but now I'm a bit confused.
I like it when objects are named properly, I don't like names like "it" for "item" or "aItem" for new items. I prefer names to be semantically correct.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if you are off-topic for SO, but this question may be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Vulkan Honestly i don't have understand what exactly you wants do,but what i have understand i would like to tell you it's upto you that how you have given naming conventions.Which object you want to use. But avoid to create global object is good practices.

Comment: You can use NSArray -enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: to avoid your naming issues 
[self.items:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
...
}];